# how to prevent users from viewing and updating another user's data in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, mongoose

I am storing a parking detail with a merchant id in the mongoose schema since a parking belongs to a certain merchant user and it cannot be empty or null.

Here is the model:

```
const parkingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  merchantId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "Merchant",
  },
  //other details
})
```

merchant model is something like this:

```
const merchantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  merchantId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Auth",
    },
  //other details
 })
```

And finally the auth schema:

```
const authSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    accountType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        default: "user",
        enum: ["merchant", "user", "provider"],
      },
    //other details
  })
```

If the original user wishes it, I simply want to update the parking data; otherwise, I want to throw an error.

I am using `jsonwebtoken` to authenticate users.

Here is the query to update the data:

```
exports.updateParking = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { parkingName, price, address, name, phoneNumber, about } = req.body;
    const { parkingImage } = req.files;
    const check_exist = await Auth.findById(req.data.id);
    if (!check_exist) return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    console.log(req.data.id);

    const updateData = await Parking.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id, merchantId: req.data.id }, // I think here is the problem
      {
        $set: {
          parkingName,
          price,
          address,
          ...
        },
      }
    );
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "Parking has updated successfully",
    });
    } catch (error) {
    return error.message;
    }
    };
```

However, the issue is that other users can now update another user's data which I want to stop

below is the query of middleware:

```
routing.patch("/parking/update/:id", middleware.authenticateToken, merchant.updateParking);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent updating data from other users you must check the requested user in your updateParking function.
for example :

```
if(req.user !== req.body.user) {
   return res.status(400).json({ error: "you can't update another User" });
}
```

req.user is logged In user and req.body.user is the user you want to update.